# How undone a repo and convert it as a regular directory

Tags: git

I did git clone a model to my current working directory , but actually I execute `git clone $REPO ./`   instead of `git clone $REPO ./REPO_NAME`
So all the files inside the REPO went to my current working directory, so my current directory "becomes" a repo and I dont want that

How can I undone this? I mean that my current working directory not being a repo and back to normal dir status?

Comment: If your current directory was non-empty, `git clone` should have refused to `git clone $REPO ./`: `fatal: destination path '.' already exists and is not an empty directory.` So, if the clone worked, presumably your current directory was empty. In that case, just go up a level, make a new empty directory, then rename the old directory to a new directory within the empty directory.

Comment: my current directory was not empty and the git clone go through successfully , so in my current directory I have a combination between other folders and the repo folders

Comment: Curious. Do you have a particularly old version of Git? It *should* have failed, just as it did when I tested, but I tested with Git version 2.21.0.

Answer (score 4):

You can move the `.git` subfolder in any new folder you want. (and delete the files that were initially checked out, assuming you have not started to make any work/modifications)

Then go into that new folder (where you just move the .git) and type:

```
git checkout -- .
```

That will restore all the files from the `master` branch.

> I want my current directory dont be a "repo" type, I want my current directory go back to normal "dir" type

That will *also* restore the initial directory to its "normal" non-Git status.
Which means that simply deleting the .git folder is enough, if you don't care about the repository.
Although you might want to do *first*

```
cd /wrong/directory
git rm -r *
```

That will clear out all the tracked files that were suddenly checked out by your initial clone.
Then:

```
rm -Rf .git
```

Comment: but I dont want to restore or keep the repo, I want my current directory dont be a "repo" type, I want my current directory go back to normal "dir" type

Comment: @JCMoctezumaPuma OK: I have edited the answer accordingly. The `git rm` step is important to restore your folder in its original state.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply delete the contents inside the folder including the `.git` folder in your current repository local folder, this will make the folder changes untrackable and the repo folder will automatically be converted to the normal folder.

To verify whether the folder is a normal folder after doing the above, go to that directory in the cmd, and enter the command `git status`. It will return you the following error:

`fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

This means, that repo folder is converted to the normal folder.

I hope this was helpful.